Could not allocate space for object 'X'.'Y' in database 'Z' because the 'PRIMARY' filegroup is full
I have a limited primary data file(mdf) and an unlimited secondary data file(ndf) in the DBName database. These two data files are on different disks. I get the following error when the index maintenance job runs.
Shouldn't the index maintenance job continue via the secondary data file? Why am I getting this error?
Could not allocate space for object 'TableName'.'IndexName' in database 'DBName' because the 'PRIMARY' filegroup is full. Create disk space by deleting unneeded files, dropping objects in the filegroup, adding additional files to the filegroup, or setting autogrowth on for existing files in the filegroup. [SQLSTATE 42000] (Error 1105).  The step failed.
Thanks in advance..

Check if secondary data file(ndf) belongs to PRIMARY filegroup and not other filegroup.

secondary data file and primary data file are both in the Primary file group @SergeyA

Please check select name, is_autogrow_all_files,*
from sys.filegroups and what is your server version? Starting with 2016 you can control  AUTOGROW_SINGLE_FILE for your filegroup

I couldn't understand what I should check. @sepupic

What do you see in is_autogrow_all_files in the result of the query above

When I run the "select * from sys.filegroups" query  --> PRIMARY 1 FG ROWS_FILEGROUP 1 0 NULL NULL 0
